# Netty - `Future.operationComplete` never called when running in SSL mode in idle timeout handler

Tags: ssl, netty, future

We have implemented the following `channelIdle` implementation.

```java
public void channelIdle(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, IdleStateEvent e) 
    throws Exception {

    Response response = business.getResponse();

    final Channel channel = e.getChannel();

    ChannelFuture channelFuture
            = Channels.write(
               channel, 
               ChannelBuffers.wrappedBuffer(response.getXML().getBytes())
    );

    if (response.shouldDisconnect()) {// returns true and listener _is_ added.
        channelFuture.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
            @Override
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
                channel.close(); // never gets called :(
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When running in non-SSL mode this works as expected.

However, when running with SSL enabled the `operationComplete` method never gets called. We've verified this a few times on various machines. The idle timeout happens many times but the `operationComplete` isn't called. We don't see any exceptions being thrown.

I've tried tracing through the code to see where `operationComplete` should get called but it is complex and I've not quite figured it out.

There is a call to `future = succeededFuture(channel);`  in `SslHandler.wrap()` but I don't know if that means anything. The future returned from `wrap` is never used elsewhere in the `SslHandler` code.

Comment: Note to anyone who's interested. This issue is being addressed here: https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/604

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug.. Would it be possible to write a simple "test-case" that shows the problem and open an issue at our github issue tracker[1].

Be sure to explain if it happens all the time or only sometimes etc..

[1] https://github.com/netty/netty/issues

Comment: I think I found the problem.. This may be related to: https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/601